# I want to iterate through the <ul> children

Tags: reactjs

By clicking the `<Fatimes color='red' .../>` icon, I want to iterate through the unordered list element using the `key` and `value` in the iteration process, but I don't have an idea on how to go through with it.

```
const Cards = ({arr}) => {
  return (
    <ul className='output'>
      {arr.map(e => {
        return <li key={e.id} className="card" >
          {e.value}
          <FaTimes color='red' style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} onClick={e => console.log(e.value)}/>
        </li>
      })}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

I want to use `map` to iterate through, but I don't know what to use as anchor point.

Comment: I think it needs further explanation about what you want to do?  Can you explain why you want to iterate? Maybe I can offer another point of view.

Comment: I want to iterate so that when I click the icon i can delete any card with duplicate values